# How do i maintain the value of the loop variable in a setTimeout? Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops

Basically, i have a loop where if a certain condition is met, it fires a setTimeout.
But the timeout function requires the value of the loop ( i.e 'i'), as example below.
How do i do that?

```
 for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if(something){
      setTimeout(function(){
         console.log(i);
      }, 1000);
    }
 }
```

Comment: FYI, modern browsers let you pass extra arguments to `setTimeout` which show up as callback arguments. `setTimeout(function(i) { console.log(i); }, 1000, i);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use **[IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression) (immediately-invoked function expression)**, it is a JavaScript design pattern which produces a lexical scope using JavaScript's function scoping.

```
 for( var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
    if(something){
        (function(i){
            setTimeout(function(){
               console.log(i);
            }, 1000);
         })(i);
     }
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, learned something new

Comment: sure,  "You can accept the answer in 5 mins."

Comment: @user3783888: Do you understand the cause of the initial problem and how the solution works?

Comment: yes, i think.. as  the value of i changes when the timeout function calls it. So, when it is immediately invoked the current value of i is passed in that function.. right? or smth else

Answer (score 0):

```js
for (var i = 0; i <= 10; i++) {
  if (true) {
    setTimeout((function(i) {
     return function() { console.log(i); }
    })(i), 1000 * i);
  }
}
```

and I think you want the time to be `1000 * i` ? (It's already in the code above)